# Error when passing pointer to imported Extension type method while having no problem with the same class without import

Tags: python, c, class, cython

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**: reproducible example [here](https://github.com/iamishalkin/cython_class_issue)

I have code similar to one in [documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#instantiation-from-existing-c-c-pointers), so that the class is created from pointer. It works perfectly, when both class definition and class instance creation are in the same file.

main.pyx:

```py
cdef some_type * ptr_to_wrapped_type = <some_type *>malloc(sizeof(some_type))

#next part from documentation
cdef class WrapperClass:
    """A wrapper class for a C/C++ data structure"""
    cdef my_c_struct *_ptr
    cdef bint ptr_owner

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass from_ptr(my_c_struct *_ptr, bint owner=False):
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects from
        given my_c_struct pointer.
        Setting ``owner`` flag to ``True`` causes
        the extension type to ``free`` the structure pointed to by ``_ptr``
        when the wrapper object is deallocated."""
        # Call to __new__ bypasses __init__ constructor
        cdef WrapperClass wrapper = WrapperClass.__new__(WrapperClass)
        wrapper._ptr = _ptr
        wrapper.ptr_owner = owner
        return wrapper
...

data = WrapperClass.from_ptr(ptr_to_wrapped_type, owner=True)
```

What I want is to move class definition into separate file and import it in main. This is also described in [docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types) and that's what I have:

wrapper.pxd:

```py
# Example C struct
ctypedef struct my_c_struct:
    int a
    int b

cdef class WrapperClass:
    """A wrapper class for a C/C++ data structure"""
    cdef my_c_struct *_ptr
    cdef bint ptr_owner
```

wrapper.pyx(class definition from [docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#instantiation-from-existing-c-c-pointers)):

```py
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free

cdef class WrapperClass:
    """A wrapper class for a C/C++ data structure"""
    cdef my_c_struct *_ptr
    cdef bint ptr_owner

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.ptr_owner = False

    def __dealloc__(self):
        # De-allocate if not null and flag is set
        if self._ptr is not NULL and self.ptr_owner is True:
            free(self._ptr)
            self._ptr = NULL

    @staticmethod
    cdef WrapperClass from_ptr(my_c_struct *_ptr, bint owner):
        """Factory function to create WrapperClass objects from
        given my_c_struct pointer.
        Setting ``owner`` flag to ``True`` causes
        the extension type to ``free`` the structure pointed to by ``_ptr``
        when the wrapper object is deallocated."""
        # Call to __new__ bypasses __init__ constructor
        cdef WrapperClass wrapper = WrapperClass.__new__(WrapperClass)
        wrapper._ptr = _ptr
        wrapper.ptr_owner = owner
        return wrapper
...
```

And finally in main.pyx:

```py
cdef some_type * ptr_to_wrapped_type = <some_type *>malloc(sizeof(some_type))

from wrapper cimport WrapperClass

data = WrapperClass.from_ptr(ptr_to_wrapped_type, owner=True)
```

Unfortunately, at compilation I get an Error:

```
data = WrapperClass.from_ptr(ptr_to_wrapped_type, owner=True)
                            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

Cannot convert 'some_type *' to Python object
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you define a `@staticmethod` function for your `WrapperClass` called `from_ptr`?

Comment: @CodeSurgeon, Yes. Changes in method are minimal. Literaly I added only one assignment, in doc example terms it looks like `wrapper.new_var = _ptr.b` and of course I added `cdef int * new_var` at the beginning of the class

Comment: @DavidW, as an expert in cython, can you, please point me out the mistake?

Comment: In your not working example on github, when you use a .pxd (header) file, all cdef and cpdef functions need to be listed there as well (without the implementation/function body). That way, these functions are accessible when you cimport the class into other .pyx modules. That is why your main.pyx can't find the WrapperClass's from_ptr function.

Comment: @IvanMishalkin - the comma after my name meant I didn't get notified (might be useful to know this...). CodeSurgeon is right though (and should probably write this up as an answer)

Comment: @CodeSurgeon thanks a lot, if you post your comment I'll mark it as answer. I also edited my git repo, so now everything works fine [git](https://github.com/iamishalkin/cython_class_issue/tree/master/not%20working(fixed))

Comment: Alright, I have posted it as an answer now. Glad to see it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your not working example on github, when you use a `.pxd` (header) file, all `cdef` and `cpdef` functions need to be listed there as well (without the implementation/function body). That way, these functions are accessible when you `cimport` the class into other `.pyx` modules. That is why your `main.pyx` can't find the `WrapperClass`'s `from_ptr` function.